# Direct summands of successive extensions of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

On a projective variety any direct summand of a direct sum of line bundles is going to be direct sum of a subset of initial line bundles. This follows from the Krull-Schmidt property of vector bundles on projective varieties. Now my question is a little bit similar to this. Let's assume the vector bundle is constructed by taking successive extensions of a set of line bundles in the form $\mathcal{O}(n)$. Is any direct summand of this vector bundle in the similar form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not. Let $X$ be a smooth **curve** and take any line bundle $\mathcal{L}$. Then for $n \gg 0$ the bundle $(\mathcal{L} \oplus \mathcal{L}^{-1}) \otimes \mathcal{O}(n)$ is globally generated. Therefore, a general morphism
$$
\mathcal{O}(-n) \to \mathcal{L} \oplus \mathcal{L}^{-1}
$$
is a fiberwise monomorphism, hence its cokernel is a line bundle, which by computing the determinant can be identified with $\mathcal{O}(n)$. Thus, we have an exact sequence
$$
0 \to \mathcal{O}(-n) \to \mathcal{L} \oplus \mathcal{L}^{-1} \to \mathcal{O}(n) \to 0
$$
which shows that **any** line bundle on $X$ is a direct summand of an extension of $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

Comment: This extension is an element of $H^{m-1}(X,\mathcal{O}(2n)\otimes \omega_X)$ by Serre duality. Here let $m>1$ be the dimension of $X$. Let's assume we are in char $p$. Then by applying Frobenius this cohomology group becomes eventually trivial. This implies the splitting the exact sequence after applying Frobenius. Let's say $k$ times applying of Frobenius is required. So we have $\mathcal{O}(kn)\oplus \mathcal{O}(-kn)\cong F^{*k}(L)\oplus F^{*k}(L^{-1})$. This implies that $F^{*k}L$ should be $\mathcal{O}(kn)$ or $\mathcal{O}(-kn)$. This doesn't seem to be true for any $L$.

Comment: I was talking about the curve case. In higher dimension often there are no nontrivial extensions, so there is nothing to talk about.

Comment: Is there a more precise reference or statement of the fact "In higher dimension often there are no nontrivial extensions"? (I want to understand what exactly often means here)

Comment: If $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is sufficiently ample (and characteristic is zero) all line bundles $\mathcal{O}(n)$ with $n > 0$ have trivial $H^1$ by Kodaira vanishing and all line bundles $\mathcal{O}(n)$ with $n < 0$ have trivial $H^1$ by Kodaira vanishing and Serre duality. So, if also $\mathcal{O}$ has trivial $H^1$, there are no non-trivial extensions.